# Bigquery - calculate bandwidth of a query response

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery, bandwidth

I want to calculate the bandwidth i.e: `(response size)/(time taken)` of all the queries I execute in bps.

*For example*, If I execute a `SELECT` query I want to get the response size and get the time taken to reach it to my end. Then divide it to get bps.

Response size I can get using `statistics.load.outputBytes` ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#statistics.load.outputBytes)) for a particular job id. But how can I get the time interval (Send time from bigquery and receive time from my end)?

There is a `statistics.endTime` ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#statistics.endTime)) I thought of assuming this as the response send time. But since its the job end time I doubt that assumption too.

Is there a way that I can get the bandwidth directly from api or any other indirect way?

Note: I use Python 2.7.11

Comment: It's a long shot, but you can use that `endTime` and your connection drop time to get interval.

Comment: I doubt you can get anything from `statistics.load.outputBytes` for the query. it rather used for load

Comment: @Pentium10 how can I get that? can I get the response size also the same way?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant BigQuery doesn't expose the output size?

Comment: it does not, from what I know!